# Show that the function $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x) = x^2$ is not a homomorphism.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Pretty confused by this. How is this not a homomorphism?

$f(ab) = (ab)^2 = a^2b^2 = f(a)f(b)$

What am I missing?

Comment: Since you used the group theory tag, I assume that mean a group homomorphism.  But what is the binary operation on $\Bbb R$? Note that $\Bbb R$ is **not** a group under multiplication.

Comment: What a question !  And why $(ab)^2$ would be equal to $a^2b^2$ ? As I know, $(ab)^2=(ab)(ab)$... You are missing a lot of things : what is the context ? Which group are you talking about ?

Comment: "You are missing a lot of things" Yes I know, I am struggling pretty hard :(
The really sad part is I've spent a lot of time reading the chapter and working on these on my own before I ask anything here *sigh*. 
There is no context, that is the question, there are no qualifiers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The group operation on $\mathbb{R}$ is addition, so in order for $f$ to be a homomorphism, it must satisfy
$$f(a+b)=f(a)+f(b)$$
for every $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$.
However
$$f(1+2)=(1+2)^2=9\ne5=1^2+2^2=f(1)+f(2).$$

The function $f:\mathbb{R}^*\to\mathbb{R}^*$ given by $f(x)=x^2$,
where $\mathbb{R}^*$ is the multiplicative group $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$,
is a homomorphism (as you've shown).

Comment: Really stupid question, but if the group operation is addition, why is $x^2$ not $x + x$?

Comment: The question is indeed out of context... this answer has no sense... you are only making an obvious uninteresting answer... (-1)

Comment: @btcgurl It's not a stupid question at all. In the context of group theory, $x^2$ means $x\cdot x$ (in a multiplicative group) and $2x$ means $x+x$ (in an additive group). Here $\mathbb{R}$ has both addition and multiplication, but only the first of these is the group operation. (Note that $0$ does not have a multiplicative inverse.) It wouldn't make much sense to write $x^2$ for $x+x$ when the author could just as easily write $2x$.

Comment: @Surb The only thing the question lacks is that "group homomorphism" should be in the place of "homomorphism". However this isn't at the fault of btcgurl, because he/she likely hasn't been exposed to enough abstract algebra to see its necessity. This answer is my best attempt to clarify the OP's issues. It's intention is to be helpful, not interesting. I'm sorry you aren't satisfied. If you have anything constructive, I would be happy to learn it.

Comment: @JohnGriffin ok, I think I see, I'm not sure why I was under the impression that the only operation you could perform in a function is the group operation, other than that's all we've dealt with so far. I very much appreciate the help